# How can i create table rows containing form elements in django?

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a template, where is a form with inputs like, description, qty, price.

and down of the template have a table, what i want is; when push click on button the data goes to the table.

one thing* i want like django inline admin but in views, is like a detail-invoice, and after of all, when i click on save (example) this data goes to the model

other thing** how can i calculate the qty * price and put in other field

Comment: Most of what you are asking must be achieved using javascript on the template. I recommend using js, jquery and -in some cases where you may need to talk to the server- ajax.

Comment: The closest thing in Django and a solid place to start are [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/). They are basically the equivalent to the inline admins in Django Admin. Like @Alvaro said, the dynamic parts (like creating a new row on button click or calculating a value based on other values) of your use case will be best done with Javascript.